# Create user with eloquent prepared statement

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I would like to create a database user using something like the following prepared statement:

```
DB::statement("CREATE USER ? IDENTIFIED BY ?", ['abc', 'def']);
```

However, attempting to run this gives me an error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? IDENTIFIED BY ?' at line 1 (SQL: CREATE USER abc IDENTIFIED BY def)

I can create like this:

```
DB::statement("CREATE USER {$user} IDENTIFIED BY {$password}");
```

But I would prefer not to use a prepared statement, how can I achieve that?

Comment: Surely if you are using `?` parameters you have to prepare and bind values to those parameters?

Comment: `$user = 'abc'; $passwod = 'def'`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
DB::statement("CREATE USER :name IDENTIFIED BY :password;", ['name' => 'abc', 'password' => 'def']);
```

Comment: This gives the following error: "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? IDENTIFIED BY ?' at line 1 (SQL: CREATE USER :name IDENTIFIED BY :password;)"